# Restrict access to relation models with "include" LoopbackJS

Tags: loopbackjs

I have two models A and B. A has many B, B belongs to A. I want to have A openly accessible but B would be private only to the $owner of A. I can easily restrict access to the route GET /api/B but what about "include"?
If I run GET /api/A with {filter: {include: 'B'}} I will get all B.
This example is pretty simple, only two models. I could add some code in A.beforeRemote('find') that would allow only users access this data but in real app relations chain is longer, A hasMany B, B hasMany C. Do I have to build this logic by myself in each place where "find include" chain can start or there is a way to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

The hidden property on the model should work, e.g. "hidden": ["password"]